# Two question on Permutation and Combination

Tags: combinatorics

1.Find the number of ways in which a mixed double tennis game can be arranged between 10 players consisting of 6 men and 4 women.

My approach : Since,if every pair of selection of men and women gives rise to 4 matches so **C(6,2) * C(4,2) * 4.**

2.Find the number of ways in which a mixed double game can be arranged from amongst nine married couples, if no husband and wife play in the same game.

My approach : **C(9,2) * C(7,2) * 4.**

Now, this two questions comes from my test paper I would be grateful if somebody check whether this is correct or not since my answers doesn't matched to the given solution in the paper.

Comment: I get a final factor of 2 rather than 4.

Comment: @ Robin Chapman : Could you please explain your idea ? My idea is like this if we select `M1,M2` and `W1,W2` then the team can be constituted in 4 ways : `M1,W1; M2,W2; M1,W2; M2,W1;`

Comment: Debanjan, that looks like two possible matches to me.

Comment: Sorry i didn't get you :|

Comment: @ Debanjan: I think your list is the list of possible teams, not the list of possible matches (M1,W1)v(M2,W2), (M1,W2)v(M2,W1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to (1) is 2*C(6,2)*C(4,2) (and not with a 4), since M1, W1 playing M2, W2 is the same as M2, W2 playing M1, W1. I don't think the question wants you to take account of which end they're playing from. You've made a similar error in part(2).

To make it more clear you've included a factor 2 for swapping the women over, say, in our set of four people, and then included another factor of 2 for swapping the men over, but have of course ended up with the same match when both swaps have taken place.

Comment: So in both the problem the factor will be 2 ?

Comment: @Debanjan: Yes.